# PDO Fetching Bcrypted password?

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, fetch, salt

I have been a lot of troubles with my code since I first started learning something about hashing and salting passwords. First, I learn how to "hash" passwords with MD5 (Yeah, don't do that anymore), then with hash and SHA256 and finally now with bcrypt (Or at least i thinks it is bcrypt). Here's my registration code for now:

register.php

```
<html>
<head>
<title>PDO - hashing algorithm</title>
</head>
<body>
    <?php
        if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {
            define( "DB_DSN", "mysql:host=localhost;dbname=test" );
            define ( "DB_USER", "root" );
            define ( "DB_PASS", "" );

            try {
            $connect = new PDO (DB_DSN, DB_USER, DB_PASS);
            $query = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `users` (
                    `id` INT(11) PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT NOT NULL,
                    `username` VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
                    `password` VARCHAR(500) NOT NULL
            )ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8 DEFAULT COLLATE utf8_swedish_ci;";
            $stmt = $connect->prepare($query);
            $stmt->execute();

            } catch (PDOException $e) {
                echo $e->getMessage();
            }
            // Let's hash the password
            $salt = substr(str_replace('+', '.', base64_encode(sha1(microtime(true), true))), 0, 22);
            $hashedpassword = crypt($_POST['password']. '$2a$12$' .$salt);
        try {
        $query = "INSERT INTO `users` (`username`, `password`) VALUES (:username, :password)";
        $stmt = $connect->prepare($query);
        $stmt->execute(array(
                            ':username' => $_POST['username'],
                            ':password' => $hashedpassword
                        ));
                if ($stmt->rowCount() == 1) {
                    echo "Well done, user has registered successfully";

                } else {
                    echo "An error occured.. Please try again";
                }
        } catch (PDOException $e) {
            echo $e->getMessage();  
        }
    }
    ?>
    <form action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];?>" method="post">
    <p>Username: <input type="text" name="username"/></p>
    <p>Password: <input type="password" name="password" /></p>
    <input type="submit" name="submit" />
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

This code does work and will crypt the password, so that was not my main question. My main question is, how do I compare the user inputted password and the password stored in db when I want to create a login page?

here's my login.php atm. Tell me if you see something that I don't but I cannot get this to work, it won't output username and password from the database.

```
<?php
        try {
        define( "DB_DSN", "mysql:host=localhost;dbname=test" );
        define ( "DB_USER", "root" );
        define ( "DB_PASS", "" );

            $connect = new PDO (DB_DSN, DB_USER, DB_PASS);

        } catch (PDOException $e) {

            echo $e->getMessage();
        }

        if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {

        $query = "SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE (username) = :username";
        $stmt = $connect->prepare($query);
        $stmt->execute(array(
                        ':username' => $_POST['username']
                        ));
            if($stmt->rowCount() == 0) {
                echo "User doesn't exist";
            } 
                $row = $stmt->fetch();

                if (crypt($_POST['password'], $row['password']) == $row['password']) {
                    echo $row['username']. $row['password'];
                } else {
                    return false;
                }
        }
    ?>
```

Comment: Fetch the bcrypt hash from the database using the supplied user ID/name. The fetched value *should* contain the salt and the number of rounds as well as the result of the hash. Then use this, along with the supplied user input, to generate a new bcrypt value and compare - the authentication is valid if and only if they are the same value. I am quite certain this is shown in examples. Or, better, use a tidy library/wrapper. (Unlike a broken password hashing approach without salt, it requires first fetching the salt, so that it can be used to compute the challenge hash.)

Comment: I edited my comment below with a code sample to hopefully help you as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please see this link for a tutorial on how to do it: [Using bcrypt to store passwords](http://oscarm.org/2012/6/using-bcrypt-store-passwords)

EDIT:

I found some of my working code that I will post here to hopefully help.

First, I use a custom function:

```
function better_crypt($input, $rounds = 7){
    $salt = "";
    $salt_chars = array_merge(range('A','Z'), range('a','z'), range(0,9));
    for($i=0; $i < 22; $i++) {
        $salt .= $salt_chars[array_rand($salt_chars)];
    }

    return crypt($input, sprintf('$2a$%02d$', $rounds) . $salt);
}
```

Then when the account is first created, store the $password_hash in the database:

```
$password_hash = better_crypt($_POST['password']);
```

Then when logging in, compare the submitted password versus the password hash in the database:

```
// $password = submitted login form password
// $row['password'] = the password hash in the database
if(crypt($password, $row['password']) == $row['password']) {
//Success!
```

Comment: I updated my comment to hopefully be more clear and make more sense.

Comment: Thank you for your code "snippet".. It helped me alot! One more question, though it worked. While you created that better_crypt function, what value that input variable gets?

Comment: If you look at the second code snippet I posted, you see that I pass $_POST['password'] to the better_crypt function.